# Is it possible to use past continuous tense and tell a long-term action after when?

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

Is it possible to use past continuous tense and tell a long-term action after when?

Is it possible if I say

> - When my sister read the novel, I was watching a movie.
> - When my sister ate ice cream, I cooked for dinner.
> - When I was running, I broke my leg.

Comment: ***When*** usually applies to a ***point in time***, whereas ***while*** usually refers to a ***period of time***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three of your examples, **while** fits the context far better than **when** - although the use of **when** in the final example sounds more idiomatic. Your examples are not strictly wrong; but they can be improved.

Because reading a novel and watching a movie are both time-consuming actions - activities that stretch over a period of time - **when** doesn't work well here. **While** is used to indicate continuity, an action that took some time.

**When** would be fine for **When he knocked on the door** or **When my sister picked up the novel** as these are momentary actions. You are then talking about what you were doing (continuous) at the point when something happened.

You could also use a continuous tense for both clauses if you preferred:
**While my sister was reading the novel, I was watching a movie**.
Alternatively:
**While my sister read the novel, I watched a movie.**

There is very little difference. The choice of tense depends on your preferences and the context. Different tense work better in different situations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Ronal Sole. It was very clear.